# function that takes variable length as argument and returns tuple

Tags: python-2.7, set, tuples, args

I have written code as below:

```
def convTup(*args):
    t = set([])
    for i in args:
        t.add(i)
    return tuple(t)

print convTup('a','b','c','d')
print convTup(1,2,3,4,5,6)
print convTup('a','b')
```

Expected output :

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
('a', 'b')
```

But I got output as below:

```
('a', 'c', 'b', 'd')
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
('a', 'b')
```

Why has the order of the elements changed only for `('a','b','c','d')`? How can I print the tuple in the same order as the given input?

Comment: 1) your indentation is off 2) why not just `return tuple(args)`?

Comment: @JohnColeman If your parameter is a list, tuple(args) would raise a TypeError

Comment: corrected indentation & return tuple(args) will give the expected output.But i want to know why the order is changing only for ('a','b','c','d') .

Comment: @Vinny What do you mean? `def f(*args): return tuple(args)` doesn't raise a type error with `f([1,2,3])`

Comment: @JohnColeman it doesn't for list, but if you use the `set` collection it does cause a TypeError for `set(tuple(args))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this and you'll have a tuple sequence as your input

```
>>> def f(*args):
    p = []
    [p.append(x) for x in args if x not in p]
    return tuple(p)

>>> f(1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> f('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

This function will create a **list of unique elements and track their order** then return it as a tuple.

You can see the same functionality using a **set** instead of **list**. A set doesn't keep track of the order the elements were entered.

```
>>> def tup1(*args):
    l = {x for x in args}
    return tuple(l)

>>> 
>>> tup1('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'b', 'd')
```

You can implement your own **SortedSet** collection if you use it in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
def convTup(*args):
    return sorted(tuple(set(args)), key=lambda x: args.index(x))
```

Sou you convert args into `set` that is ordered by default, then turn it into `tuple` and finally sort that `tuple` by the original order.

So, to be precise, this function is ordering by order of appearance taking into account only the first appearance of element in args.